# Jusqu'alors ou jusqu'à lors ?

Tags: orthographe, adverbes, indications-de-temps

Laquelle de ces deux phrases est correcte ?

- *Je n'ai encore rien reçu jusqu'alors.*
- *Je n'ai encore rien reçu jusqu'à lors.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On écrit ***jusqu'alors***.

Le *Trésor de la langue française* donne :

> **ALORS** (I. A. 3. a.)
>   *Jusqu'alors*. Jusqu'à ce moment-là, jusqu'à cette époque :
>   Je n'aimais point le peuple *jusqu'*​**alors**, mais dès lors j'eus pitié de lui. *(A. Gide, El Hadj,1899, p. 359.)*
>   <sub>[TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/alors)</sub>

Même si d'après le dictionnaire de l'Académie, *alors* vient bien de *à* et *lors* :

> **ALORS**, adv.
>   XII<sup>e</sup> siècle ; rare jusqu'au XV<sup>e</sup> siècle. Composé d'*à* et de *lors*.
>   <sub>[Académie, 9](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/alors)</sub>

Comment: Since the form *dès lors* exists, even though *jusqu'alors* might be more common, *jusqu'à lors* might not be as incorrect as it is unusual.

Comment: @Benjamin Since it is not in any reference dictionary, those who care about correctness would probably dub it as incorrect. But I have not.

Answer (score 4):

La forme la plus correcte est il me semble :

> Je n'ai encore rien reçu jusqu'à présent.

*Alors* (en un mot) est un adverbe qui désigne *ce moment-là*, et il ne me viendrait probablement pas à l'idée de l'utiliser pour désigner le moment présent. Pour désigner une limite passée ou future, il faut employer l'auxiliaire avec le temps correspondant :

> Je n'avais/aurai encore rien reçu jusqu'alors.

Comment: Effectivement ce serait plus français. Ma question portait sur le jusqu'alors et ma phrase d'exemple n'est pas idéale en fait.